# Javascript array filter: getting the context right

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

While trying to write some awesome JS I ran into some strange JS-behaviour. I've created a piece of code to demonstrate my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/CeyCy/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      var images = $('.images').children();
      var filtered = images.filter(function(i, image) {
        console.log(this);
      }, "abc");
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="options">
      <div class="filters">
      </div>
      <ol class="pagination">
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="results">
      <ul class="images">
        <li data-category="Zakelijk">Result 1</li>
        <li data-category="Speels">Result 2</li>
        <li data-category="Blogging">Result 3</li>
        <li data-category="Zakelijk">Result 4</li>
        <li data-category="Speels">Result 5</li>
        <li data-category="Blogging">Result 6</li>
        <li data-category="Zakelijk">Result 7</li>
        <li data-category="Speels">Result 8</li>
        <li data-category="Blogging">Result 9</li>
        <li data-category="Zakelijk">Result 10</li>
        <li data-category="Speels">Result 11</li>
        <li data-category="Blogging">Result 12</li>
        <li data-category="Zakelijk">Result 13</li>
        <li data-category="Speels">Result 14</li>
        <li data-category="Blogging">Result 15</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ok, now my question. When using the Array.filter method you pass in a callback function as first parameter and an optional context as second parameter. As you can see, I'm passing "abc" as context (which is ridiculous, ofcourse). I would expect my console to throw a lot of "abc", but instead it prints the jQuery elements!

Can someone shine some light on this please?

Thanks,

Martijn

Comment: You're not using the Javascript `Array.filter()`, you're using jQuery's [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As you can see, I'm passing "abc" as context (which is ridiculous, ofcourse). I would expect my console to throw a lot of "abc", but instead it prints the jQuery elements!

You're using [jQuery's `filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), which doesn't have a context parameter, rather than  ES5's [`Array#filter`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.20), because you're calling `filter` on a jQuery object, and jQuery objects are not arrays (although they offer a lot of array-like functionality, and several "methods" with similar names — including `filter`).

Three options for you:

#### `makeArray`

You can use jQuery's [`makeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) to turn the jQuery object into an array, e.g.:

```
$(function() {
  var images = $.makeArray($('.images').children());
  var filtered = images.filter(function(i, image) {
    console.log(this);
  }, "abc");
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CeyCy/1/)

#### `proxy` / `bind`

Or alternately, you can use jQuery's [`proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function (or ES5's [`Function#bind`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5)) to bind the iterator function you're passing to jQuery's `filter` so it ignores the `this` jQuery supplies:

```
$(function() {
  var images = $('.images').children();
  var filtered = images.filter($.proxy(function(i, image) {
    console.log(this);
  }, "abc"));
});
```

#### Apply `Array#filter` to the jQuery object

**Or** you can apply `Array#filter` directly to the jQuery object:

```
$(function() {
  var images = $('.images').children();
  var filtered = Array.prototype.filter.call(images, function(i, image) {
    console.log(this);
  }, "abc");
});
```

...since `Array#filter` is *expressly defined* to work on anything array-like, not just `Array`s. That last might actually be the most efficient way to do it. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CeyCy/3/)

Comment: Ah crap, thanks.. have had the same issue (using jQuery methods instead of plain-old-javascript methods) several times now >.<

Comment: @MartijnDwars: LOL no worries, glad that helped. I added two more options for you, the last of which avoids creating unnecessary temporary objects.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive explanation! It really helps a lot when getting familiar with JS & jQuery.

Comment: @MartijnDwars: You're welcome! If you're interested in learning more about JS, [I blog about it periodically](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/search/label/javascript).